# DLNA or UPnP libraries for Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to write a DLNA controller application for my windows phone 7, that would stream media from server to media renderers. Is there any DLNA or UPnP library available for WP7 as of now? Or how easy/difficult it is to port Intels DLNA .Net libraries to WP7 platform.
Any suggestion will be of great help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are sockets available in the Mango toolkit, but not in the current one. You could create a web service which has the UPnP functionality and wrap it so that it can be consumed by your app. It's not as efficient as using it directly from the device but, as far as I know, that's the only viable option.